TS 7023 Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{}'
I am getting select-box options, iterate labels, optgroup & values into select-box.  Is there anything wrong with the way I have created my types?
interface Option {
  label: string
  value: string
  selected?:boolean
  mainGroup?: string
  optgroup?: "" | string | [] | undefined
}

const trackNames: Option[] = [
  {
    value: "Track1",
    label: "Track One",
    optgroup: "",
  },
  {
    value: "Track2",
    label: "Track Two",
    optgroup: "",
  },
  {
    value: "Track3",
    label: "Track Three",
    optgroup: "Track3-Group",
  },
  {
    value: "Track4",
    label: "Track Four",
    optgroup: "Track3-Group",
  }
];

// sample.js code
import { trackNames as trackNameData } from '/helper/Data'

const groupedOptions = {};
  
trackNameData.forEach((option: { optgroup: any; value: any; label: any }) => {
    
  if (!groupedOptions[option.optgroup]) groupedOptions[option.optgroup] = [];
    groupedOptions[option.optgroup].push({
      value: option.value,
      label: option.label,
  });

});

const renderOptions = (options: any[]) => {
   return options.map((option) => {
     return (
       <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
         {option.label}
       </option>
       );
    });
};

<select>   
    <option value=''>Please select</option>
    {Object.keys(groupedOptions).map((group, index) => {
    return (
      <optgroup key={index} label={group}>
      {renderOptions(groupedOptions[group])}
    </optgroup>
    );
    })}
</select>

When I am importing trackData into another JS file to show otions in Select-box gave me below error:
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{}'.ts(7053)

What am I doing wrong? I've looked at other solutions and can't get it to work.

The error pretty much says it all. const groupedOptions = {}; makes your groupedOptions to be typed as an empty object without any properties.
When you then do if (!groupedOptions[option.optgroup]) (with option.optgroup typed as any) you are trying to access a property, of groupedOptions the TS-compiler isn't aware, it can exist. Thus, for ensuring compile-time type safety, this is not allowed.

But that's not the only problem with your code. The optgroup property, you are trying to use as property name, is typed as "" | string | string[] | undefined (don't know why you just widen that up to any any in your forEach). What would you expect your code to do if optgroup is an empty array or undefined? What would you expect groupedOptions[undefined] or groupedOptions[[]] to do?

Yeah I know, that's allowed in JS, because if you do something like let foo = []; let bar[foo] = baz  it implicitly calls foo.toString() in the assignment. But in TS, the index type of an object is limited to string and number. And you should take this hint from TypeScript, to only use strings for property access. This will prevent shooting yourself in the foot and observice rather strange errors later on.

if optgroup is an empty array or undefined? I am expecting groupedOptions[[]]

Actually I have taken code reference from below link
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/8z319o6yvl?file=%2Fsrc%2Findex.js%3A42%2C18
trackNameData i have imported from another js file & that const I have added in sample code i.e. trackNames
renderOptions - sorry I forgot to add code but now I have add into code.

Well, since you're already liberally using any, you could just make groupedOptions of type Record<string, any> as shown in this playground link.  I wouldn't say that's a good idea, but it avoids the error because now groupedOptions allows any key and any value. Does that meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Thanks for playground link, now error is resolved. please write up an answer so I can approve. Thanks

I will do so when I get a chance.

If you're going to be indexing into groupedOptions with some arbitrary key, then you want to give it a type with an index signature. From your code example as given I'd expect you want the values to be arrays of Options. So the type {[k: string]: Option[]} or the equivalent Record<string, Option[]> (using the Record utility type) would work:
const groupedOptions: Record<string, Option[]> = {};

Once you do that, it will not be an error to write groupedOptions[xxx] as long as xxx is keylike:
trackNames.forEach((option: { optgroup?: any; value: any; label: any }) => {
  if (!groupedOptions[option.optgroup]) groupedOptions[option.optgroup] = [];
  groupedOptions[option.optgroup].push({
    value: option.value,
    label: option.label,
  });
});

That now compiles as written without error.  But do note that you have given optgroup the intentionally loose any type which mostly turns off type checking. Generally speaking you should only be indexing into objects with strings, numbers, or symbols.  If optgroup can really be undefined or an empty array [] (note that [] is a tuple type of zero elements and not an arbitrary array type), then indexing into an object with it will have surprising results. I'm considering this out of scope for the question as asked, but you should really make sure that your object keys are valid.
Playground link to code

interface Option {
  label: string
  value: string
  selected?:boolean
  mainGroup?: string
  optgroup?: "" | string | [] | undefined
}

const trackNames = [
  {
    value: "Track1",
    label: "Track One",
    optgroup: "",
  },
  {
    value: "Track2",
    label: "Track Two",
    optgroup: "",
  },
  {
    value: "Track3",
    label: "Track Three",
    optgroup: "Track3-Group",
  },
  {
    value: "Track4",
    label: "Track Four",
    optgroup: "Track3-Group",
  }
] as const satisfies Option[];

const groupedOptions: { [key in typeof trackNames[number]['optgroup']]: { value: string, label: string }[] } = {} as any;
  
trackNames.forEach((option) => {
  if (!groupedOptions[option.optgroup]) groupedOptions[option.optgroup] = [];
  groupedOptions[option.optgroup].push({
    value: option.value,
    label: option.label,
  });
});

